# Displaying error message from Apex Code

Tags: apex, error-messages

How to display error message at the top of page in Salesforce from Apex? (I'm not using Visualforce)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can display error messages using the addError method on sobject or its fields.

Salesforce docs on the sobject instance addError method: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError

More info on exception handling: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Exception_Handling

Comment: Thank you for your answer. addError works, however it appends "Error: Invalid Data. Review all error messages below to correct your data." before the error message. Any ideas how to disable that?

Comment: Other ways you could go about it are to call addError on a specific field like Account.Name.addError('').  This would give you a different, but smaller prefix to the error.  Additionally, you could write a validation rule on the sobject to show an error instead of handling it in Apex.  This would show a Validation error instead of Invalid data.  If none of those suffice, the only other route is more customization through either Visualforce or Javascript.

Comment: I think using Visualforce would be too much for this scenario. Then I would need to add a page and a controller. I am searching the web how to call JavaScript from Apex class but couldn't find the solution. Is it even possible? (Regular Apex class, not controller)

Comment: Fixed link in case someone else will try to click the first link in the answer above: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError